# Python: Looking for more efficient method of sorting list into sublists accounting for missing input

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, matrix

I'm still somewhat new to Python 3, and while I have something that works, I think it could be a lot more efficient and readable.

For example, if I have the input:

```
A1, B1, C1, A2, B2, A3, C3, C4
```

I want to convert this into columns (so I can ultimately put it into an excel spreadsheet) that look like this:

```
 1   A    B    C
 2   A    B    None
 3   A    None C
 4   None None C
```

My code looks like this:

```
locations  = ["A", "B", "C"]
log        = [["A",1],["B",1],["C",1],["A",2],["B",2],["A",3],["C",3],["C",4]]
day        = [ [] for x in range(10) ]  # can I dynamically allocate this as I go?

i = 0

for index, element in enumerate(log):
    if (log[index][1] != log[index-1][1] and index != 0):  # if the number changes
        for place in locations:                           
            if place not in day[i]:                        # if something's missing
                day[i].insert(locations.index(place),None) # insert a None where its missing
        i += 1

    if element[0] in locations:                            
        day[i].append(element[0])

for place in locations:     # the loop ends without doing the last list so I call 
    if place not in day[i]: # this again, is there a way to keep it in the loop?
        day[i].insert(locations.index(place),None) 

day = [x for x in day if x != []]   # strips empty lists from list

columns = list(zip(*day))           # transposes matrix
```

And my output is:

```
 [('A', 'A', 'A', None), ('B', 'B', None, None), ('C', None, 'C', 'C')]
```

So my question is: How can I make this more efficient? Can I allocate the lists inside the list as I go? And how to I keep it all inside the for loop?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that builds out the array while reading the log:

```
days = []
for loc, day in log:
    for i in range(len(days), day):
        days.append([i+1] + [None for _ in locations])
    days[day - 1][1 + locations.index(loc)] = loc

print(days)
```

[[1, 'A', 'B', 'C'], [2, 'A', 'B', None], [3, 'A', None, 'C'], [4, None, None, 'C']]

Comment: Wow! That's really clean. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a dictionary with location tuples as keys, and start with a default `None` value.

```
columns = ("A","B","C")
rows = (1,2,3,4)
table = { (col, row):None for col in columns for row in rows}
```

Then you can edit your table by looping through your log,.. turning the location key/value in table that match a value in your log, into the respective log/table col value.

```
log = [["A",1],["B",1],["C",1],["A",2],["B",2],["A",3],["C",3],["C",4]]

for cell in log:
    if tuple(cell) in table:
    # if tuple(cell) in table.keys(): if python 2.7
        table[tuple(cell)] = cell[0]

print [ tuple(table[col,row] for row in rows) for col in columns]

[('A', 'A', 'A', None), ('B', 'B', None, None), ('C', None, 'C', 'C')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is more efficient, but it's more concise:

```
>>> locations  = ["A", "B", "C"]
>>> log        = [["A",1],["B",1],["C",1],["A",2],["B",2],["A",3],["C",3],["C",4]]
>>> maxi=max(i for [_,i] in log)
>>> d = {i:list() for i in locations} #d={'B': [], 'A': [], 'C': []}
>>> for [letter,i] in log:
...   d[letter].append(i)
... #d={'B': [1, 2], 'A': [1, 2, 3], 'C': [1, 3, 4]}
>>> [tuple(letter if i in d[letter] else None for i in range(1,maxi+1)) for letter in locations]
[('A', 'A', 'A', None), ('B', 'B', None, None), ('C', None, 'C', 'C')]
```